# Windows Shell Command for Turning on Bluetooth

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I have been having some issues where my Bluetooth is not functioning correctly on my windows 10 device. I have probably accidentally clicked `Airplane Mode` and that can result in a well-known glitch whereby the Bluetooth services themselves are disabled and not necessarily turned back on. This also results in the `Bluetooth` icon to disappear from the settings.

The conventional wisdom for this error is to open up Microsoft services and turning on any services that may pertain to Bluetooth. I.e:

```
Windows Key + R > services.msc
```

**Question:** While I have nothing against the above approach, but I was hoping that I could run some command(s) from the shell itself to turn on the relevant services instead of pointing and clicking amidst the hundreds of services. Is there such a method?

Comment: You mean like `net start <Bluetooth-service-name>`?